# Passing JSON object and service to a component through binding

Tags: angularjs, binding

I'm trying to build a component which is basically a "CRUD list". On the top of the component there is a form. Under this form there is a list of existing objects.

For exemple you can have a form to create a car, you have two fields "car name", "car model". Under this form you have the list already created cars.

I build a generic component which use a datamodel to display the fields and the list. The data model looks like this :

```
ctrl.dataModel =  {
            "fields" : [
            {"fieldName":"name", "fieldDescription":"Nom", "fieldType":"boolean"},
            {"fieldName":"description", "fieldDescription":"Description de l'application", "fieldType":"boolean"}
        ],
        "dataName":"Applications"
};
```

The component works well when I set manually the datamodel and datas. I can now use this tag into HTML fragments :

```
<crudlist></crudlist>
```

I want to "pass" a datamodel to this crudlist component, so I made this binding declaration :

```
angular.
module('CrudlistModule').   
component('crudlist', { 
bindings: { 
    datamodel:"=",  
},

templateUrl: 'modules/crudlist/crudlist.template.html', 
controller: [crudlistController]
}
);
```

But when i try to inject anything into datamodel by using this code :

```
<crudlist datamodel="ANYTHINGHERE"/></crudlist>
```

it seems that datamodel is undefined in the controller. I used a simple "console.log("...")" to display it.

In order to see what is defined into the controler I've done this :"console.log(ctrl);", and I never see any datamodel of any kind.

You can find all files here : http://plnkr.co/edit/6x8b2IC2YAvZJG0TVcDl

Thank a lot if you can help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking quickly:

- component defines the controller as var ctrl = this;  but the default for a component is $ctrl, so you'll either want to add controllerAs: 'ctrl' or change ctrl to $ctrl.
- defines the controllerAs: 'ctrl' but in your template you are using $ctrl.
- You're also not including the CrudListModule in the application module dependencies.

I'm not sure if there are any other issues, but those two things jumped out when looking.  Once you get everything on either $ctrl or ctrl you'll be a little more set, you probably also want to include the index.html and pull it all together so you can see it in action.